# Joining two arrays in a json to one array in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

In Nifi, I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "list1":[1,2,3],
  "list2":[4,5]
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
{
 "Final_List":[1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor with a ***shift*** type transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "Final_List"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit *for special case* :**
If it was the case that those arrays have some common integer elements, then the above solution would yield repeating elements within the `Final_List`, but the following make that result having unique elements for this case too :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Final_List.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Final_List": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toInteger(@(1,Final_List))"
    }
  }
]
```